# Show that the solution of the system remains in a region for all future time $t \geq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the system of equations
>
> \begin{cases}
> \dot{x} = x(1- x^2 - y^2)\\
> \dot{y} = y(4- x^2 - y^2)
> \end{cases}
>
> Define $(x(t;(x_0,y_0)), y(t;(x_0,y_0)))$ as the solution of this system with initial condtition $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, so $(x(0;(x_0,y_0)), y(0;(x_0,y_0))) = (x_0 , y_0)$.
>
> Suppose that the initial condition $(x_0,y_0)$ lies in the region $S \subset \mathbb{R^2}$, with
>
> $S = \{(x,y) : x>0 , y>0$ and $1 < x^2 + y^2 < 4 \}$.
>
> So $(x(0;(x_0,y_0)), y(0;(x_0,y_0))) = (x_0 , y_0) \in S$.
>
> Show that $(x(t;(x_0,y_0)), y(t;(x_0,y_0))) \in S$, for all $t \geq 0$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} (x(t;(x_0,y_0)), y(t;(x_0,y_0))) = (0,2)$.

Well, for $(x,y) \in S$ we have $\dot{x} <0$ and $\dot{y} > 0$. Then, $x(t)$ is a monotonic decreasing function of time, and $y(t)$ is a monotonic increasing function of time.

A Lemma in my textbook says that in this case any solution $x(t)$, $y(t)$ must leave a region at some later time. This confuses me, since I have to show that a solution remains in the region for all $t \geq 0$. Maybe I am misinterpreting something.

Furthermore $(0,2)$ is clearly a critical point of the system. How can be showed that the limit approaches $(0,2)$?